# Deploy WPF application on a friend PC

Tags: wpf, client, execution, setup-project

I developed a WPF application that connects to SQL server DB. I'm using SQL server express edition and visual studio community edition. I need to run the application on a friend of mine (who is the client). I don't need to publish it to any servers. I published the application and I had the setup.exe file generated. When I run the setup file on my friend's PC then run the application, the application opens but without displaying anything. Do I need to install SQL express on my friend PC and .NET framework as well or what can I do?

Comment: _"Do i need to install sql express on my friend PC and .NET framework as well or what can I do?"_ -- if SQL Server Express were not installed on the PC, what server instance would your app connect to? Your question is unclear. On the one hand, it seems like you'd know what server your app tries to connect to; on the other hand, it seems like if you knew that, you'd know whether the server needs to be installed on the PC or not. What about all that is unclear to you?

Comment: This is my first time for me to develop and deploy wpf application. I need to know the best practice in my case. Please advise if you can support.

Comment: _"I need to know the best practice in my case"_ -- sounds like you need to _get it to work_ first. Once you have something that actually works, _then_ you can worry about whether your implementation fits the community's opinion of what the "best practice" is.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you must understand, than any instanse of SQL serve - is another application, that works without your app.

Second, in .NET Framework, exists some providers to work with SQL Server, there live in
[System.Data.Sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient?view=netframework-4.8) and [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.server?view=netframework-4.8)

System.Data.Sql - needs you to connect to SQL Server, and run queries. Second namespace to work with SQL Server objects.

When you create empty WPF Application - it works without any data connections, just empty WPF Form. So, you write a code to connect to SQL Server, where you describe SQL server network address, and security kind (sql login + password, or SSPI to use windows identity) in SqlConnection string, [see more](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=netframework-4.8)

Then you can open connection to sql server (don't forget for firewall), and then run your query to get data.

So, you don't need instal SQL server on any machine where you use your app. In some cases you need to install SQL types via SQLSysClrTypes.msi, but non SQL instance.

Yo can se how to create simple WPF app with entity framework (to work with sql data) [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/create-a-simple-data-application-with-wpf-and-entity-framework-6?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Thank you. But I need to know why the application is not displaying anything after I created the setup.exe file and run it on my friend pc. I already finalized the application and now It is not working. I thought that I might need to install sql server on his machine but now as I understand no it is not required. So can you advise how can I deploy it to my friend machine and resolve this issue?

Comment: You can use ClickOnce to distribute your application. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/clickonce-security-and-deployment?view=vs-2019
So. If your app correctly installed, but when you run it - neve changes. See application logs in OS. There are can be some events, why app not started or crashes. I recomended you to use ClickOnce, because it simple, and you get manifest file, with checks for version of .Net Framework and some other components used by your app before install it on another computer.